# Clarification of "First Year Choice" in IRS pub. 519, U.S. Tax Guide for Aliens?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

In [IRS Publication 519](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p519.pdf), on page 9:

What is the purpose of "First Year Choice"? I mean how would it help a taxpayer?

Also in the example if Juan DaSilva is considered resident from Nov 1, 2010 then will he be taxed on worldwide income he earned **before** Nov 1, 2010 or only on worldwide income he earned **after** Nov 1, 2010? Can you please clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to [this portion](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_publink1000222177), then yes - if Juan DaSilva chooses to be treated as resident, then both Señor and Señora DaSilva will be taxed as residents **for the whole year**.

Note that if Señor DaSilva is single, or married to another Señor DaSilva - then he cannot make the choice.

It can help the taxpayer if the worldwide income is the same as the US income, but they want to itemize deductions. It can also help with taxes in their home country, if they're taxed as residents in the US (depending on the local laws and treaties).

**correction**

Reading your comment I see that you're referring to a different portion. Yes, in this case Señor DaSilva will only pay on the world-wide income for the part of the year he considers to be resident.

This is for people in transition from non-residency to residency. This might not always be good for the taxpayer, but in some cases it might be beneficial. Partial resident cannot claim standard deduction, but can itemize, and if there's a lot to itemize it might be beneficial. The choice is available to those who're definitely going to be residents for tax purposes the next year.

Comment: Same article but I am referring to material under "First Year Choice". In the example Juan DaSilva is treated as Resident only from Nov 1, 2010 ( and not for the whole year). Right??

Comment: @abc right. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks littleadv, appreciate it. You see I am in exactly this situation. I am resident for 2011 but my wife started working in US from Oct 1 2011 and before that she was working in UK. Now if I treat her as full year resident then I pay tax on her UK income also. Even after form 1116 it is quite high. I can treat her as non resident and file married filing separately. But I was looking for some options to reduce my tax bill. So I am thinking this first year choice might be of use to me. Are you aware of any catches while using this "First Year Choice"?

Comment: @abc - you don't have to use it at all. If she is not resident by the green card/substantial presence test, she can file NR for the whole year. Depending on the US-UK tax treaty, that might be better. I just helped some friends in a similar situation, they chose to file NR for the whole year. They would get all their taxes back either way, and just filed one form instead of two.